# On the generators of $H_n(D^n, \partial D^n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Given the $n$ dimensional disk $D^n$, I want to find a generator of $H_n(D^n, \partial D^n)$ for $n \geq 2$, where $H_n$ is the $n$-th singular homology group.

A solution for this problem can be found in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology, Example 2.23*, but I'd like to solve it differently.
By replacing $(D^n, \partial D^n)$ with the standard $n$-simplex $(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)$, I consider the identity $\iota: \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$, which is a cycle. I'd like to show that $\iota$ generates $H_n(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)$ (and that would yield that $\phi_\ast [\iota] = [\phi]$ generates $H_n (D^n, \partial D^n)$, where $\phi: (\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n) \to(D^n, \partial D^n)$ is the homeomorphism "rounding" the edges), i.e. I'd like to show that for every $[\sigma] \in H_n(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)$, $[\sigma] = n [\iota]$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $\sigma: \Delta^n \to \Delta^n$ is also a map of pair from $(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)$ to $(\Delta^n, \partial \Delta^n)$ itself, $\sigma_\ast$ would be a morphism and then $[\sigma] = \sigma_\ast [\iota] = n [\iota]$, but I can't see why this in general should be true, even though I've found some [reference online](https://folk.ntnu.no/gereonq/MA3403H2018/MA3403_Lecture07.pdf) showing that this idea works. Any hint or opinion is be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you work in simplicial homology, this is pretty straightforward. The $n$ dimensional chains are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, generated by the lone $n$ dimensional simplex. The generator is a cycle as you have shown, while there are no $n+1$ dimensional chains, so it can't be a boundary.

Comment: Is there a reason you expect this to be easier than the general statements about homotopy invariance or comparing simplicial and singular homology?

Comment: @ronno I didn't expect this to be easier, but while studying, this was the first idea that came up to my mind, but I couldn't make it work for the reason above, hence the question.